# Please tell me what's the name of the metal wrap

Tags: roof, roofing, rust-proofing

Can someone please tell me what's the name of the metal wrap in the first pic? It wraps the top of the wall on my roof top. My roof has a rubber layer on it and it goes up to inside the wall. On top of the wall, it is the metal wrap. It is old and cracks open, which causes leaks in my apartment. What's the name of this metal wrap if I need to replace it? How much normally does the material cost (per square, unit, etc.)? Thanks so much!

Carrie

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generically, that's flashing. There might be an additional term that escapes me at the moment to describe it's precise function here at the top of the wall, or parapet. Apartment you rent, it's the landlord's problem - call them, get it fixed. Apartment you own, might be your problem, might be a matter for the owner's association as something that affects the whole building, not *just* your apartment. Depends on the terms of ownership.

Comment: Wall cap  perhaps

Comment: Looks to me like the flashing is copper, though hard to tell for sure, and the problem is at the seams.  If it is copper, someone should be able to re-solder the joints.  But, I think it's the apartment building owner's responsibility to correct.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  as per her other question today, she is the landlord/owner of the building.    Roof leaks can be difficult to find the right spot where the water is coming in.  What looks like the place, might just be nearby the leak.

Comment: The wet spot may even be distanst from the leak if there is steel channel involved in the roof structure.

Comment: Thanks all! Cap flashing. That is all I need to know. The leaks start with one/two spots on the top edge of the my living room sliding door. We had heavy rain yesterday and now seven spot across the top edge. Most likely I have to replace the part of cap flashing right above my living room.

Comment: It's called *trim coil* and you need a sheet metal break. But it doesn't need to be replaced, it needs to be taken out, or pried up and cleaned, and then put back in with new caulk, with the drip edges still functional and not all full of caulk.

Answer (score 2):

Parapet cap, or parapet wall cap.
Cost would depend on material choice and dimensions as it's likely something custom made.

Answer (score 1):

combining Kris and Ecnerwal's answer that's a "cap flashing" cost is off topic.

Usually these are made to order at sheet-metal shop (ask at a plumbers supplier)
when you go to place an order (with a drawing and dimensions) they will tell you the cost.

It may be that the incorrect method has been used to make this connection and that a join capable of moving is needed here. It looks intact if it's not corroded, possibly only the join needs to be replaced with an expansion joint.

Comment: Thanks Jasen! Someone used solar seal on those joints a few days ago. But, it is still leaking. I guess if we can't find the cause of the leaks, we will have to replace the whole cap flashing.

Comment: My suspicion is that you need a real roofer to deal with this. Faulty flashing is certainly a thing, but noticeable leakage suggests that the roof membrane is compromised.